# Getting latest value in analysis Quicksight

Tags: amazon-quicksight, quicksight-embedding

I'm having a problem with what should be a very simple solution.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFTbm.jpg

How can i get the latest value xyz and abc in the field C .
Very new to quicksight.

There might be a simple solution that
I might not know about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to have a new calculated field which has the latest value of C for each column (A, B etc..), then you could add these as follows:

**latest A**

```
maxOver(
  ifelse(
    {Date} = maxOver({Date}, [A], PRE_FILTER), C,
    null
  ),
  []
  PRE_FILTER
)
```

**latest B**

```
maxOver(
  ifelse(
    {Date} = maxOver({Date}, [B], PRE_FILTER), C,
    null
  ),
  []
  PRE_FILTER
)
```

and so on